# Why is my Android Simulator black when I run Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, android

Whenever I try to run the code for my app in `Xamarin Visual Studio 2017` it shows a black screen with nothing at all. I'm following this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/YwWOAWmNMXQ?t=961) and it doesn't seem to work for me. It gives no errors other than the:

> Android_Accelerated_Nougat will run unaccelerated

which from what I've seen is not a prominent enough issue that would cause my simulator to be completely black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need check your Update, because the earliest version VS2017 has some problem with Simulator.
The second, you check your PC's Ram. If it's large, It's will run quickly

Finally, If your PC use win7, I can Install Genmotion [www.genymotion.com](http://www.genymotion.com). if your PC use win10, you can install Microsoft Emulator for Android http://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator. It's so quickly